# Right-click to select a datagridview row

Tags: .net, datagridview

How do you select a datagridview row on a right-click?

Answer (score 23):

Make it behave similarly to the left mouse button? e.g.

```
private void dataGridView_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more flexible and complete than JvR's answer, but you should add a check for `e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0` in case the user right-clicks on a header.

Answer (score 15):

```
    // Clear all the previously selected rows
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in yourDataGridView.Rows)
    {
      row.Selected = false;
    }

    // Get the selected Row
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo info = yourDataGridView.HitTest( e.X, e.Y );

    // Set as selected
    yourDataGridView.Rows[info.RowIndex].Selected = true;
```

Comment: If your DataGridView has MultiSelect set to false then clearing the previous selection is unnecessary. Also, HitTestInfo can return HitTestInfo.Nowhere if the hit is not a valid Row/Column.

Comment: Can't .ClearSelection help to speed up things?

Answer (score 5):

the cool thing is add a menu on that right click, for example with option like "View client information", "verify last invoices", "Add a log entry to this client", etc.

you just need to add a ContextMenuStrip object, add your menu entries, and in the DataGridView properties just select the ContextMenuStrip of it.

This would create a new menu in the row the user right clicked with all the options, then all you need to do is make your magic :)

remember that you need JvR code to get what row was the user in, then grab the cell that contains the Client ID for example and pass that info.

hope it helps improving your application

http://img135.imageshack.us/img135/5246/picture1ku5.png

http://img72.imageshack.us/img72/6038/picture2lb8.png

Answer (score 3):

Subclass the `DataGridView` and create a `MouseDown` event for the grid,

```
private void SubClassedGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Sets is so the right-mousedown will select a cell
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo hti = this.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    // Clear all the previously selected rows
    this.ClearSelection();

    // Set as selected
    this.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

from `@Alan Christensen` code convert to VB.NET

```
Private Sub dgvCustomers_CellMouseDown(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgvCustomers.CellMouseDown
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        dgvCustomers.CurrentCell = dgvCustomers(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

I am tested on VS 2017 it working for me!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
End If
```

code works in VS2019 too

Answer (score 0):

You can use JvR's code in the MouseDown event of your DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things:

1. Clear all rows and Select the current. I loop through all rows and use the Bool Expression `i = e.RowIndex` for this
2. If you have done Step 1 you still have a big pitfall:
   DataGridView1.CurrentRow does not return your previously selected row (which is quite dangerous). Since CurrentRow is Readonly you have to do

   `Me.CurrentCell = Me.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)`

   ```
   Protected Overrides Sub OnCellMouseDown(
       ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)

       MyBase.OnCellMouseDown(e)

       Select Case e.Button
           Case Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right
               If Me.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = False Then
                   For i As Integer = 0 To Me.RowCount - 1
                       SetSelectedRowCore(i, i = e.RowIndex)
                   Next
               End If

               Me.CurrentCell = Me.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
       End Select

   End Sub
   ```